# Как мне в dataset получить id последней строки?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, typed-dataset

Мне нужно передавать Id последней строки. А как его получить я не знаю. Пишу на C# ASP.Net web forms. В таблице три значения "Id" , "Title", "Message". 
Добавляю значения в таблицу вот так:

```
 MessageTableAdapter adapter = new MessageTableAdapter();
        adapter.Insert(BODY.Text, title.Text);
```

Comment: `DataRow lastRow = yourTable.Rows[yourTable.Rows.Count-1];`

Comment: Как я понимаю, id генерируется автоматически в БД? И вам нужно получить id вставленной именно в БД строки? И укажите используемую СУБД.

Comment: Да id генерируется автоматически, да нужно получить id последней вставленной строки. БД у меня облачная, находится на Azure.

Comment: См. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3704394/5045688

Comment: А там чего нибудь похожего на linq нет? а то OrderByDescend и FirstOrDefault.